How to limit children while left joining in typeorm?
I'm using TypeORM with PostgreSQL in my Nest.js application. I have two entities, User and Photo, with a one-to-many relationship (one user can have multiple photos). I'm trying to retrieve users along with at most 5 photos for each user using TypeORM's query builder.

Is there a specific reason to use the query builder instead of standard native SQL?

@Stefanov.sm, It would be better to avoid raw SQL considering numerous joins and if-else conditions already present in the actual codebase using query builder.

And probably the use of the query builder is the very reason to have these numerous joins and if-else conditions already present? Why use clumsy and crypric proprietary syntax that expresses declarative logic in imperative terms (!) at all instead of clean standard SQL that is easy to read and understand?

You are right. I was trying to navigate my way through the query builder so that i do not have to re-write the code. If not, i will go with raw sql.

The last time I had this use case, I resolve it with this way (Two Queries needed):
    // 1. Fetch all users
         const users= await this.userRepo
                .createQueryBuilder("user")
                .getMany();
   // 2. Loop through users and fetch photos with limit
          for (let user of users ) {
                   user.photo =  await this.photoRepo
                          .createQueryBuilder('photo')
                          .where('photo.user= :id' , {user.id});
                          .limit(5) // Set the desired limit here
                          .getMany()
             }
      //return users

